# Get the time from the last post in seconds

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write up a query that will give me the time since the last post in seconds, something along the lines of

```
SELECT (NOW() - mydatetime) as val1 FROM posts ORDER BY mydatetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

How do I get `val1` in seconds?

Comment: Come on, make a bit of an effort! At least *look* in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in *seconds*, you can simply subtract the two dates as timestamps:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydatetime) FROM ...
```

**Note:** MySQL has a set of [Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), I encourage you to browse through them.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, mydatetime, NOW())
```